# Ubuntu wont boot after driver update

Tags: boot, drivers, updates

I was trying to get litrus work so I followed the steps below and then when I reboot I am stuck with the lines at the bottom. I would really appreciate some help.

Things I did:

"If you have Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver or Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish:

Add kisak-mesa PPA:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
Enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already):

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
Upgrade your system:

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Install support for 32-bit games:

sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
Install support for Vulkan API (will be functional only if you have a Vulkan capable GPU):

sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
Reboot to apply changes.

Note: Only Ubuntu 18.04 and higher is supported for AMD and Intel graphics.

Note for Intel integrated graphics users: Only Skylake, Kaby Lake, and Coffee Lake offer full Vulkan support. Broadwell, Haswell and Ivy Bridge only offer partial support, which may not work with a lot of games. Sandy Bridge and older lack any Vulkan support whatsoever."

What I see when I boot:

Note: I could not upload a photo these are what is typed on screen:

```
/dev/vvme0n1p2: recovering journal
/dev/vvme0n1p2: clean, .... filee ... blocks
Created slive User slice of gdm.
Starting user manager for UID 121...
Started session c1 of user gdm
Started user manager for UID 121.
Starting Daemon for power management...
Started Daemon for power management.
```